# module factory pattern: $inj Unknown provider: productResourceProvider

Tags: angularjs

Struggling to get a factory pattern working with angular and $resource. I seem to get an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productResourceProvider <-
>   productResource <- ProductListCtrl

Below are the various js module files:

My app.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("sampleapp",
                        ['common.services']);

}());
```

common.services.js

```
(function (){
'use strict';

angular
        .module('common.services',
                ['ngResource'])
        .constant('appSettings',
        {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:32642"
        });

})();
```

my factory

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('common.services')
            .factory('productResource',
                    ['$resource',
                     'appSettings',
                     productResource])

    function productResource($resource, appSettings)
    {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + '/api/products/:id');
    }

})
```

Finally the actual module that uses the factory:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("sampleapp")
        .controller("ProductListCtrl",
                     ['productResource', ProductListCtrl]);

    function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
        var vm = this;
        productResource.query(function (data)
        {
            vm.products = data;
        }); 
    }
}());
```

and my script load order is as follows (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="sampleapp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">Acme Product Management</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'app/products/productListView.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- Application Script -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="common/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="common/productResource.js"></script>
    <!-- Product Controllers -->
    <script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code looks good..did you forget to add `common.services.js` in your page?

Comment: Just added the html - i think my script load order is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to call the function of your factory by adding `()` at the end of it. Since it is not called, the module is not declared to Angular, that's why you get the `Unknown provider` error:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('common.services')
            .factory('productResource',
                    ['$resource',
                     'appSettings',
                     productResource])

    function productResource($resource, appSettings)
    {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + '/api/products/:id');
    }

})();
```